# Installing package using Pip install on MacOS 10.15

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, macos-catalina

Using Python3.7.3, MacOS 10.15

Can't install package - feather
tried pip3 install feather

returns error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/vl/pzz3tlxx6_d5p38wth_1nnwr0000gn/T/pip-install-3p9h1fgs/feather/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/vl/pzz3tlxx6_d5p38wth_1nnwr0000gn/T/pip-install-3p9h1fgs/feather/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/vl/pzz3tlxx6_d5p38wth_1nnwr0000gn/T/pip-install-3p9h1fgs/feather/
    Complete output (31 lines):
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/var/folders/vl/pzz3tlxx6_d5p38wth_1nnwr0000gn/T/pip-install-3p9h1fgs/feather/distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
        raise ImportError
    ImportError
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

All I'm trying to do is avoid this error in spyder

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feather'

Can someone help me as to why I'm running into an issue like this

Comment: Is there more to your error message? E.g. something on the line of "During handling of above exception, another exception occured"?

Comment: Would be nice if you would answer questions, otherwise it might be difficult to pinpoint your problem

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm running version setuptools (41.0.1), somehow I fixed the issue, I just reinstalled all packages and it now works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like setuptools is missing. 
Try `pip3 install setuptools`

this is where the error is reported.

```
            # Setuptools 0.7b and later is a suitable (and preferable)
            # substitute for any Distribute version.
            try:
                pkg_resources.require("setuptools>=0.7b")
                return
            except (pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound,
                    pkg_resources.VersionConflict):
                pass

            if not hasattr(pkg_resources, '_distribute'):
                if not no_fake:
                    _fake_setuptools()
                raise ImportError
```

What is the version number of setuptools?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (41.0.1)

Comment: what is the version number of setuptools?

Comment: running version 41.0.1 of setuptools